# tailfile and routeText not working correctly in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to nifi .  I am trying to parse a log file which keeps updating every second  wherein I need to perform a tailFile and subsequently RouteText based on some condition.

```
INPUT DATA :
[ 19/Mar/2021@00:10:01.946 :18:Thread-0:PrintEvents.java:eve:199 ] Domain: sq ,Event Type: ATT_VALUE_CHANGE
[0] notificationId := 2820417
[1] ObjectName := {ET=HOAL_SET} {NE=10.253.207.114} {LOCATION=/remote_unit=1-1-12/shelf=1}
[2] ObjectType := LOC
[3] emsTime := 20210319001001.0
[4] neTime := 19700101052959.0
[5] edgePointRelated := false
[6] AttributeList := { AdditionalInfo = { {AVAILTIME=1616092801888} {distance=752}  }  }

[ 19/Mar/2021@00:10:26.247 :18:Thread-0:PrintEvents.java:eve:199 ] Domain: sq ,Event Type: ATT_VALUE_CHANGE
[0] notificationId := 2820419
[1] ObjectName := {ET=HOAL_SET} {ManagedElement=10.253.204.178} {LOCATION=/remote_unit=1-2-3/shelf=1}
[2] ObjectType := LOC
[3] emsTime := 20210319001026.0
[4] neTime := 19700101052959.0
[5] edgePointRelated := false
[6] AttributeList := { AdditionalInfo = { {AVAILTIME=1616092777000} {dt=6510} {st=2} {opttime=1616092826143}  }  }


ROUTE CONDITION :
```

[image]

The issue is that from the input the notificationID 2820417 is not getting matched in the RouteText and thereby many more such notifications are getting missed . I think the tailFile is also not reading all the data line by line. Please help here.

Comment: nifi is not tailing file line by line. it reads file by available blocks. you can use splittext to split block to lines

Comment: I am already using split content. Even then I face the same issue